# SQL Return only duplicate records

Tags: sql, count, subquery, sql-server-2017

[image]

I want to return rows that have duplicate values in both Full Name and Address columns in SQL. So in the example, I would just want the first two rows return. How do I code this?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Does your table have a primary key?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...?

Answer (score 2):

Why return duplicate values?  Just aggregate and return the count:

```
select fullname, address, count(*) as cnt
from t
group by fullname, address
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Comment: I guess for this I don't really want to aggregate it. There are other variables in the table that will be different even when the fullname and address are the same. I'm not sure how to tackle this

Comment: @hauger2 . . . This provides an answer to the question you asked.  GMB's answer is the answer you want.

Answer (score 1):

One option uses window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, count(*) over(partition by fullname, address) cnt
    from mytable t
) t
where cnt > 1
```

If your table has a primary key, say `id`, you can also use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where exists (
    select 1 
    from mytable t1 
    where t1.fullname = t.fullname and t1.address = t.address and t1.id <> t.id
)
```