# SQL Return where name is the same but strategy is different

Tags: sql, count, subquery, sql-server-2017

[image]

I want to return all records and items where there is the same Full Name, but different strategies. And one of those strategies has to be like '%TG%'

Comment: As commented on [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64665083/sql-return-only-duplicate-records) already, please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, sqlserver...? SQL questions should always include a database tag, as different products have different functionalities and syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.fullname = t.fullname and
                    t2.strategy <> t.strategy and
                    (t2.strategy like '%TG%' or t.strategy like '%TG%')
             );
```

Comment: This does not find ones like `'%TG%'`

Answer (score 0):

If you take two queries for each requirement and get the intersection of the results then you solve your problem

```
-- Names with different strategies
SELECT FULLNAME
FROM tablenameyoudidnotsay
GROUP BY FULLNAME
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT STRATEGY) >1
INTERSECT
-- Names like TG
SELECT FULLNAME
FROM tablenameyoudidnotsay
WHERE STRATEGY LIKE '%TG%'
```

Note you could also use Gordon's query for the first part -- whichever runs faster with the indexes you have implemented.

Intersect is the same as inner join -- but I think using intersect is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with window functions. Compare the min and the max value of `strategy`: if they differ, you know there are at least two distinct values. As for "TG" strategy, you can use a window max.

So:

```
select fullname, strategy
from (
    select t.*, 
        min(strategy) over(partition by fullname) min_strategy,
        max(strategy) over(partition by fullname) max_strategy,
        max(case when strategy like '%TG%' then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by fullname) has_tg
    from mytable t
) t
where min_strategy <> max_strategy and has_tg = 1
```